# Cannot open Excel xlsx file created with 64-bit OLEDB ACE 12.0 driver on 32-bit Office workstation

Tags: c#, excel

I am running a 64-bit C# app on a server that can read and write an .xlsx file, using the OLEDB ACE 12.0 64-bit driver.

When I copy an .xlsx file written by the application back to my workstation, which is running MS Office 32-bit, and try to open it using EXCEL, I get this error:

"Excel cannot open 'such-and-such-file' because the file format or file extension is invalid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted. "

When I press CTRL+SHIFT+I, the number 101591 shows up in the message box.
I have tried renaming to .xls, and the Excel .Open + Repair option, but the file cannot be read.

Comment: The .xslx format is a fancy ZIP container.. if you rename the file extension to .zip can you open it seeing the contents?

Comment: Excluding 32/64 bit problems, are you using the same Excel version both on server and client?

Comment: To Forty3 - I renamed the file to a .zip format and can open it and see the contents.  The files created are in multiple sub-directories but I don't see any content.

Comment: To Steve - Office on the workstation is Office 2010. Office is not loaded on the server, we are just using the Access Database Engine 2010 driver